# Write amount of angle image rotates on fabric js canvas

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) project and i m trying to print amount of rotated angle ....

[image]

[image]

Using Fabric.js's function `getAngle()`. I can get angle, but how to print it on screen? ..as an image

There is website `printio.ru/classic_tees/new` (founder website of [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) library)..this is a t-shirt printing website...upload any image by clicking image option and then u can position that image wherever u want and on rotation of that image,amount of angle image rotated will also be printed...
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "As in image"? You want to add it to the fabric canvas? Why does it need to be done as an image? Please be more thorough in your description of the issue.

Comment: i uploaded two image regarding the problem...hope u will get the problem

Comment: Do you have some code, a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: I threw in some vector logic below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that it is not complete, but at least it's a start. I don't really have the time at the moment, but I would get the center of the object:

```
( obj.left + obj.width / 2 , obj.top + obj.height / 2 )
```

And then get the polar coordinates for the hover-tooltip using a vector from the center out towards the rotation handle.

[Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/srhcv1fj/)

**Edit**: The following code is updated from my original submission. I added vector logic to translate the text according to the angle of rotation. I kept the original intact in case anyone is interested.

```js
var imgSrc = 'http://placehold.it/500x300/322F37/E9EBFF.png&text=Image';
var showLine = true;

(function () {
    fitToContainer(document.querySelector('canvas#c'));

    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

    // Image - An image to rotate.
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imgSrc, function (img) {
        img.scale(0.5).set({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            lockScalingX : true,
            lockScalingY : true,
            lockMovementX : true,
            lockMovementY : true
        });
        canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
        img.moveTo(0);
    });
    
    // Line - Shows distance from center of object to text
    var line = new fabric.Line([0, 0, 0, 0], {
        stroke: 'red'
    });
    canvas.add(line);
    line.moveTo(1);
    
    // Text - Shows current rotation
    var text = new fabric.Text('0.00°', {
        top: 30,
        left: 210,
        fontSize : 20,
        fill : '#222',
        evented: false
    });
    canvas.add(text);
    text.moveTo(2);
    
    canvas.on({
        'object:rotating': function(e) {
            handleUpdate(e.target, text, line);
        }
    });
})();

// Canvas setup function
function fitToContainer(canvas) {
    canvas.style.width = '100%';
    canvas.style.height = '100%';
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
}

// Vector functions
function v_vector(x, y) {
    return { x : x, y : y }
}
function v_vector2(mag, dir) {
    return v_vector(mag * Math.sin(dir), mag * Math.cos(dir));
}
function v_add(v1, v2) {
    return v_vector(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y);
}
function v_scale(v, s) {
    return v_vector(v.x * s, v.y * s);
}
function v_displace(point, angle, distance) {
    return v_add(point, v_vector2(distance, angle));
}

// Fabric.js functions
function getLocation(obj) {
    return v_vector(obj.left,obj.top);
}
function setLocation(obj, dispacement) {
    obj.left = dispacement.x;
    obj.top = dispacement.y;
}
function isImage(obj) {
    return obj['getElement'] && obj.getElement().className === 'canvas-img';
}
function handleUpdate(obj, text, line) {
    if (isImage(obj)) {
        updateAngleText(obj, text, line);
    }
}
function updateAngleText(obj, text, line) {
    var angle = obj.getAngle() % 360;
    
    text.text = angle.toFixed(2) + '°';
    
    var centerPoint = getLocation(obj);
    var antiAngle = -angle * Math.PI / 180;
    var distanceToTop = obj.height * obj.scaleY / 2;
    var textOffset = 80;
    var distance = -1 * (distanceToTop + textOffset);
    var displacement = v_displace(centerPoint, antiAngle, distance);
    
    if (showLine) {
        updateLine(line, centerPoint, displacement);
    }
    
    var textDimensions = v_vector(text.width, text.height);
    var textLocation = v_add(displacement, v_scale(textDimensions, -0.5));    
    setLocation(text, textLocation);
}
function updateLine(line, centerPoint, displacement) {
    line.x1 = centerPoint.x;
    line.y1 = centerPoint.y;
    line.x2 = displacement.x;
    line.y2 = displacement.y;
    
    line.width = Math.abs(line.x1 - line.x2);
    line.height = Math.abs(line.y1 - line.y2);
    line.left = line.x1 < line.x2 ? line.x1 : line.x2;
    line.top = line.y1 < line.y2 ? line.y1 : line.y2;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

## Original code

```js
var imgSrc = 'http://placehold.it/500x300/322F37/E9EBFF.png&text=SUV';
    
    function fitToContainer(canvas) {
        canvas.style.width = '100%';
        canvas.style.height = '100%';
        canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
    }
    
    function isImage(obj) {
        return obj['getElement'] && obj.getElement().className === 'canvas-img';
    }
    
    function updateAngleText(obj, text) {
        var rotHandlePos = obj.oCoords.mt;
        var angle = (obj.getAngle() % 360).toFixed(2);
        text.text = 'Angle: ' + angle + '°';
        text.top = rotHandlePos.y;
        text.left = rotHandlePos.x - text.width / 2;        
    }
    
    (function () {
        fitToContainer(document.querySelector('canvas#c'));
    
        var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');    
        fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
    
        // Image
        fabric.Image.fromURL(imgSrc, function (img) {
            img.scale(0.5).set({
                left: 100,
                top: 100
            });
            canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
            img.moveTo(0);
        });
        
        
        // Text
        var text = new fabric.Text('Angle: 0.00°', {
            top: 50,
            left: 100,
            fontSize : 16,
            fill : '#FFFFFF',
            backgroundColor : '#112244',
            lockRotation : true,
            lockScalingX : true,
            lockScalingY : true,
            lockMovementX : true,
            lockMovementY : true
        });
        canvas.add(text);
        text.moveTo(1);
        
        canvas.on({
            'object:rotating': function(e) {
                var obj = e.target;
                if (isImage(obj)) {
                    updateAngleText(obj, text);
                }
            },
            'object:moving': function(e) {
                var obj = e.target;
                if (isImage(obj)) {
                    updateAngleText(obj, text);
                }
            }
        });
    })();
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy...this is what i really wanted..thnks again

Comment: @AnuragSingh: I made this code even more awesome. I added a line to show how the text is displaced. I also corrected the text position to smooth the rotation.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl : Amazing solution :)

Comment: Can you point me to any tutorials as to where can I learn about these vector movements ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  you could use `fabric.Text`.  You can see an example at http://fabricjs.com/patterns/

ie:

```
var text = new fabric.Text('Honey,\nI\'m subtle', 
    {
        fontSize: 250,
        left: 50,
        top: 0,
        lineHeight: 1,
        originX: 'left',
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
        fontWeight: 'bold'   
    });   

canvas.add(text);
```

I went ahead and created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/johnboker/sfu5w9ng/3/